# Internal server error while using flask in cs50 ide

Tags: python-3.x, flask, web-applications, cs50, internal-server-error

The code's all correct but am not able to show out the desirable output on the browser- the browser alerts an internal server message(500) and the terminal shows the following error:

> ~/tracks/ $ flask run  * Serving Flask app "application.py" (lazy
> loading)  * Environment: development  * Debug mode: off  * Running on
> https://3405db29-f322-4a37-845f-11d0e562946b-ide.cs50.xyz:8080/ (Press
> CTRL+C to quit)  * Restarting with stat [2020-09-13 07:29:50,889]
> ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET] Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446,
> in wsgi_app
> response = self.full_dispatch_request()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in
> full_dispatch_request
> rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in
> handle_user_exception
> reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in
> reraise
> raise value   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in
> full_dispatch_request
> rv = self.dispatch_request()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in
> dispatch_request
> return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint   File "/home/ubuntu/tracks/application.py", line 10, in index
> return render_template("index.html", number=number)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line
> 138, in render_template
> ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py",
> line 930, in get_or_select_template
> return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py",
> line 883, in get_template
> return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py",
> line 857, in _load_template
> template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 117,
> in load
> source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py",
> line 60, in get_source
> return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 89,
> in _get_source_fast
> raise TemplateNotFound(template) jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html
> 192.168.74.236 - - [13/Sep/2020 07:29:50] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 500 -

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Grey Li has said, your `index.html` template cannot be found either because:

- You do not have `index.html` file in your templates folder or
- The path to your `index.html` file is incorrect.

**Template nonexistent**

If the file is nonexistent, you need to create it:

```py
$ touch index.html
```

Consider your current working directory to ensure that you are creating it at the right place. The example above assumes you are at the *templates* sub-folder in your terminal. Otherwise, you may want to add the path to *templates* sub-folder as:

```py
$ touch app/templates/index.html

# wherever you might be
```

**Incorrect Path**

Simply modify your path inside `render_template`. Assume you you are using an application factory where each module has its own templates sub-folder. You would do:

```py
@bp.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
   # ...
   return render_template('auth/index.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Program is looking for a file named `index.html` in a directory named `templates` under `~/tracks` directory, but it is not found.

Answer (score 0):

The traceback often provides useful information about the problem. In your terminal output, you can see "raise TemplateNotFound(template) jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html", then you will need to check if your view function return a template called `index.html`. You either need to create the template `index.html` under `templates` folder or change the return statement.

Besides, you can enable debug mode with `FLASK_ENV`:

```
$ export FLASK_ENV=development
$ flask run
```

Then the prettied trackback will display on the browser instead of the 500 error page.